# Hamming distance of binary vectors

Tags: algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory

Heyaa!! I was trying to solve the following questions and i am stuck. I do have an intuition as to how would one solve it, but i don't know how to prove that.

Let $X = \{0, 1\}^n$ be the set of binary vectors of length $n$. For $x = (x_1 , \ldots , x_n )$ and $y = (y_1 , . . . , y_n )$ in $X$, define their Hamming distance to be $d(x, y) =$ # $\{i ∈ \{1, 2, . . . , n\} : x_i \neq  y_i\}$,i.e. the number of places where $x$ and $y$ differ.
Show that $d$ is a metric on $X$. Is it an ultrametric?

I think the first property $d(x,y) \geq 0$ is fairly obvious since that is the scope, and property 2, $d(x, y) = d(y, x)$ for all $x, y ∈ X$ can be proven using mod and absolute values (not sure how to express it), and i am finding the triangle property hard to figure out. Also, I think it is an ultrametric because the LUB of two intervals (here) would always be greater than the third?

Sorry if it doesn't make a lot of sense i'm just starting to learnt eh topic. I'll really appreciate your help!! Thanks so much!! :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! [It is advisable that you take a tour to see what we are about](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959)'s a quick guide (if nothing else, read up the part on "[avoiding no-clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/#27933)").

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Also, your question also violates another rule mentioned in the quick quide, [avoiding multiple questions in one post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671). Please edit accordingly.

Comment: @5xum I apologise for the that and thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: I would think $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ is obvious once one writes down the definition of each, as $x_i \neq y_i \Leftrightarrow y_i \neq x_i$. No need for "mod and absolute values", whatever mod means here.

Answer (score 3):

This has little to do with $p$-adic or algebraic topology as you labelled.

It is a metric. In fact, if we treat $X$ as the $\mathbb F_2^n$, a vector space over $\mathbb F_2$, or at least an abelian group. Then we may define the Hamming weight $\|x\|=\sum_i |x_i|$ where $|x_i|=1$ if $x_i=\overline 1\in\mathbb F_2$ and $x_i=0$ otherwise. If we can show this is indeed a norm, then we can define $d(x,y):=\|x-y\|=\|x+y\|$ that must be a metric, and clearly this $d(x,y)$ is the same as the Hamming distance.

Indeed, we only need to show $\|x+y\|\le \|x\| + \|y\|$. This is not hard.

It's not a ultrametric when $n\ge 2$. Take $x=(1, 0, 0, \cdots)$ and $y=(0, 1, 0, \cdots)$, we have $d(x,y)=\|x+y\|=2, d(x, 0)=\|x\|=1, d(y, 0)=\|y\|=1$, hence $d(x,y)\le\max\{d(x,0), d(y,0)\}$ doesn't hold.

Of course, it's not strictly necessary to introduce the vector space $\mathbb F_2^n$, but in most cases, this help gain more intuition and simplify the argument (to show $\|a+b\|\le\|a\|+\|b\|$ which involves only two elements is easier than $d(a,c)\le d(a,b)+d(b,c)$ which involves three elements.)

Comment: Thank you! also, can you elaborate on the proof for this?  $\mid \mid x+y \mid \mid \leq \mid \mid x \mid \mid + \mid \mid y \mid \mid$

Comment: Intuitively, you may cancel the $1$'s in the components of $x$ and $y$ if they happen to agree, but you cannot create $1$ if both of them are zero. To be more formal, $\|x+y\|=\sum_i |x_i+y_i| \le \sum |x_i|+|y_i|=\sum_i |x_i| + \sum_i |y_i| = \|x\| + \|y\|$, and you only need to show $|x_i+y_i|\le |x_i| + |y_i|$ to justify the above which boils down to check only four different cases if you have to... In other words, $\|x\|$ is really the $\ell_1$-norm for the Hamming weight on a single bit, and it's easy to check the Hamming weight is indeed a norm on a single bit.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should also argue that $d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$.

Consider three elements $x=(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}),y=(y_{1},y_{2},...,y_{n}),z=(z_{1},z_{2},...,z_{n})$ in $X$. If $i$ is such that $x_{i}\neq z_{i}$ then either $x_{i}\neq y_{i}$ or $y_{i}\neq z_{i}$. So the set $\left\{1\leq i\leq n\mid x_{i}\neq z_{i}\right\}$ is a subset of $\left\{1\leq i\leq n\mid x_{i}\neq y_{i}\right\}\cup \left\{1\leq i\leq n\mid y_{i}\neq z_{i}\right\}$. Can you take it from here?

For the ultrametric property, I am not quite sure what interval you mean. The question is whether we can find $x,y,z$ as before such that $x$ differs in more indices with $z$ than $y$ with $z$ or $z$ with $y$. My advice would be to take $n=2$ and write down all elements of $X$ and all distances between them.

Comment: Alrighty, yes, that makes sense! thanks so much :)